# Functions with Options

Tags: function-construction, options, guidelines

Suppose you want to create a function which has optional arguments. Maeder's book *Programming in Mathematica* covers the topic extensively up to version 3, but some things have changed/evolved since then.

So now what is the standard code to use for a function `func[x, ...]` which takes optional arguments?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The main change since that time seems to be that the modern way of using options is associated with  [`OptionsPattern[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html) -  [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionValue.html) commands. A typical way of defining a function would be:

```
Options[f] = {FirstOption -> 1, SecondOption -> 2};
f[x_, y_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Print[{x, y, OptionValue[FirstOption], OptionValue[SecondOption]}]
```

The `OptionsPattern[]` is a pattern which is similar to `___?OptionQ` in its *purpose*, but has subtle differences, some of which are discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617511/what-are-the-benefits-of-switching-from-rule-and-to-optionspattern-and-opti). In the same question, it is discussed what are the major differences and advantages / disadvantages of old and new approaches. You can still use the old way though. The `OptionValue` command is a rather magical function, which knows which function you are in, so that you often don't have to supply the function name explicitly. However, you can always do so, since `OptionValue` has forms with more arguments. What you can not do is to mix the two approaches: if you declare options as `___?OptionQ`, then `OptionValue` won't work.

The second difference is that there is new built-in functions  [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html), which can be used to filter options. Previously, there was a package by Maeder called `FilterOptions`, which provided similar functionality, but was not in the widespread use, just because not everyone knew about it. The typical options filtering call looks like

```
g[x_, y_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   f[x, y, Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]]]
```

Filtering options is a good practice, so this addition is quite useful.

If you wanted to pass options that belong to other functions (e.g. functions that are called inside your function `g`) you would do something like this, and it would work even if `useQ` was actually an option of the function `p`:

```
g[x_, y_, opts : OptionsPattern[{g, f, p, q}]] :=
  Module[
    {s = If[OptionValue[useQ], q[y, FilterRules[q]], p[x, FilterRules[p]]]},
    f[x, s, Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]]] 
  ]
```

Comment: Never seen `FilterRules` before. That is a useful tool!

Comment: Thank you Leonid, i was waiting for your answer :-)

Comment: @Eli: it definitely should be a function that everybody who deals with options should know.

Comment: Oh, one question. What's the reason to use `opts:OptionsPattern[]`? I typically just use `OptionsPattern[]`.

Comment: @Eli Lansey Sometimes you need to do somthing with options, for example, pass them to some function you call: `f[x,y,opts:OptionsPattern]:=g[x,y,OptionValue[FirstOption],opts]`, or, better, `f[x,y,opts:OptionsPattern]:=g[x,y,OptionValue[FirstOption],Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts},Options[g]]]`. There can be other cases when you'd like to have an explicit handle on the options passed to your function.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks!

Comment: @magma You are most welcome :). Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @Eli see my answer for a working example of `opts:OptionsPattern[]`

Comment: Note that Sequence@@ before FilterRules is not necessary.

Comment: @Faysal True, if you don't mind getting options as a nested list like `{{Option1->1,Option2->2}}`. This does not matter for `OptionValue`, and `FilterRules` will make sure that the depth of the list does not grow, but I am just used to the flat list (or sequence, when passed to a function) of options, so this is a personal preference. One of the reasons is that sometimes I also use options as rules and do some rule- substtutions with them.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I hope you don't mind me adding the `OptionsPattern[{g,f,p,q}]` case to your answer. I didn't think it worth a separate answer but it is very useful and worth mentioning.

Comment: @Verbeia Yes, sure - thanks! I was thinking of adding that when writing an answer, but then thought it may be too much detail. But upon a second thought, I should have done it.

Comment: Is it better to use a String or a Symbol for option names? Mma doesn't seem to have a clear preference.

Comment: @Whelp Symbols are more work, but can have separate doc. pages and are more discoverable. Strings are often used for sub-options. There isn't a clear-cut advice. You can look at system functions and their options to get a picture when which are used - you will find both symbols and strings used frequently. Some arguments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168288/565518) are still valid, although now I would not put as strong emphasis on symbols as I did in the past.

Answer (score 49):

Here is a practical example from a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159392/create-a-function-for-customized-tabular-representation).  I hope that it gives a good overview of the basic methods.

### Question

---

> - What would be the best way to make a function out of the below code ?
> - It would take a dataList as well as some graphical options (such as colors) as arguments and return a customized tabular representation as
>     shown below.
>
>   ```
>   overviewtheData=Text@Grid[{Map[Rotate[Text[#],
>   90Degree]&,data[[1]]]}~Join~data[[2;;]],
>   Background->{{{{White,Pink}},{1->White}}},
>   Dividers->{All,{1->True,2->True,0->True}},
>   ItemSize->{1->5,Automatic},
>   Alignment->Top,
>   Frame->True,
>   FrameStyle->Thickness[2],
>   ItemStyle->{Automatic,Automatic,{{1,1},
>   {1,Length@data[[1]]}}->Directive[FontSize->15,Black,Bold]}]
>   ```
>
> [image]

---

### Goals

1. Since the main function used is `Grid` it makes sense to allow passing options to it.
2. You have a series of options that define your table.  I want to be able to conveniently change these.
3. I want the possibility of custom options not understood by `Grid`.

---

### Implementation

I will use this sample data in all examples below:

```
data = Prepend[
         RandomInteger[99, {5, 12}], 
         DateString[{1, #}, "MonthName"] & /@ Range@12
       ];
```

#### Goal #1

An argument pattern `opts:OptionsPattern[]` is added, which matches any sequence of `Option -> Setting` arguments, and names it `opts`. (See: [OptionsPattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html) for more.)  Then, `opts` is inserted into the basic function before the other options for `Grid`.  This allows any explicitly given options to override the defaults, or new ones to be given.

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   opts,
   Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]
  ] // Text
```

Examples:

```
customTabular[data]
```

[image]

```
customTabular[data, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

#### Goal #2

The options that define your tabular format can be separated from the function body.  This will allow them to be conveniently changed or referenced.  I start by clearing the previous definition with `ClearAll`.  Then I set default [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Options.html) for `customTabular`:

```
ClearAll[customTabular]

Options[customTabular] =
  {Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]};
```

Now the function proper.  Here `Options@customTabular` gets the rules given above.

The `opts` pattern is changed to `OptionsPattern[{customTabular, Grid}]` to declare options for either function as valid options (that is all options in either `Options[customTabular]` or `Options[Grid]`).

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[{customTabular, Grid}]] := 
 Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   opts, 
   Sequence @@ Options@customTabular
 ] // Text
```

Now you can easily change the defaults with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html).  Example:

```
SetOptions[customTabular, 
  Background -> {{{LightMagenta, LightOrange}}}
];

customTabular[data]
```

[image]

#### Goal #3

Now I want to add an option that is *not* passed to `Grid`.  I choose `"Rotation"` to change the text rotation of the title row.

Again I clear the prior definition and the default options.   Notice the inclusion of `"Rotation" -> 90 Degree` in the list.

```
ClearAll[customTabular]

Options[customTabular] =
  {Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold],
   "Rotation" -> 90 Degree};
```

Now I need a way to use this new option, and I need a way to keep this option from being sent to `Grid`:

- I access the option with [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionValue.html) which will give the default if none is explicitly given.
- I pass only valid `Grid` options by using [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html).

I first join any explicit options to the front of the `Options@customTabular` list, again to override defaults.

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[{customTabular, Grid}]] :=
 Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, OptionValue["Rotation"]] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~ Options@customTabular, Options@Grid]
 ] // Text
```

Example:

```
SetOptions[customTabular, Background -> {{{LightBrown, LightYellow}}}];

customTabular[data,
  Dividers -> All,
  "Rotation" -> -90 Degree,
  FrameStyle -> {Darker@Red, Thick}
]
```

[image]

#### Addendum

To add syntax highlighting to a function like this there exists a presently undocumented form; see:

- [SyntaxInformation: take allowed options from multiple symbols – possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97411/121)

Comment: Oh man this answer helped me through hours of pain. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel you're very welcome! :-)  Let me know if you need help getting anything specific working, or just have questions about the framework I laid out here.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't need to do `Sequence @@`, though that may be a more recent change.
Also, pretty much all of the documentation I read on this was really lacking. Maybe I was just not looking in the right places, but very little of this is explained well or very thoroughly.

Comment: @ThomasH `Sequence @@` is needed in *some* cases because not all functions accept a `List` of rules as options; it is included here as a matter of practice.  I hope you found my answer useful?  I agree that the documentation is lacking but that is one reason I am here. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I found it extremely useful. I used essentially your syntax, but I did the option `Join`ing as a local `tempopts` variable that I passed, after appropriate `FilterRules` to everything I call. That way I can, without further additions, add more default options to the main function for any function I call or just add the options when the main function is called, and it will be sent where it is needed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in the final goal, do we need to pass `customTabular` and `Grid` to `OptionsPattern[ ]` in the `customTabular` function definition because it is working for me even without passing them i.e. keeping `opts : OptionsPattern[]`

Comment: @AliHashmi Good question.  Given the way that I am explicitly filtering the options with `FilterRules` I think one could use `OptionsPattern[]` equally well, but I typically think of the fully qualified `OptionsPattern[{symbols . . .}]` as good practice.  I shall consider your point and possibly revise this answer.

Answer (score 19):

For additional reference, [found within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675387/198315) the file `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/English/Messages.m` are all of the defined messages for the system, and there are 11 [`General`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/General.html) messages for `Options` that do not conform. The list is

```
General::optlist = "Value of option `1` -> `2` should be a list."
General::optb = "Optional object `1` in `2` is not a single blank."
General::optrs = "Option specification `1` in `2` is not a rule for a symbol or string."
General::opttf = "Value of option `1` -> `2` should be True or False."
General::optpn = "The value of `1` -> `2` should be a positive machine-sized real number."
General::opttfa = "Value of option `1` -> `2` should be True, False, or Automatic."
General::opttfna = "Value of option `1` -> `2` should be True, False, None, or Automatic."
General::optv = "Value of option `1` in `2` is not valid."
General::optvg = "Value of option `1` -> `2` should be `3`."
General::optvp = "Invalid option value at position `1` in `2`. Allowed values are `3`."
General::optx = "Unknown option `1` in `2`."
```

As they are `General` messages, they can be used with any function as follows,

```
Message[f::opttfa, "SomeOpt", SomeOptValue]
```

Comment: I was aware of some of those but I never bothered to find them all.  Good reference.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `grep General::opt Messages.m`. :)

Comment: Hi, @rcollyer. What does 1 and 2 mean? For example, if I define `ClearAll[f1]; f1[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[a];` then `Trace@f1[a->11]` will get message "OptionValue::nodef,Unknown option `1` for `2`.". What does it mean?

Comment: @matheorem They're placeholders for a [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html), so that additional arguments can be supplied to a `Message`. In your `Trace` you find `Message[OptionValue::nodef, a, f1]` where `a` and `f1` are "slotted" into their respective placeholders in the string.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank you so much, very clear explanation : )

Answer (score 16):

Providing optional arguments to functions is rather straight forward.
I'll show you three possibilities.

1. **Positional arguments**

   This defines a function with a second optional argument. If the argument is omitted it is taken to have the default value.

   ```
   fx[list_, panel_: True] := fx0[list, panel]
   ```
2. **Named arguments**

   This sets up a default value for a named optional argument.

   ```
   Options[fx] = {panel -> True}
   fx[list_, OptionsPattern[]] := fx0[list, OptionValue[panel]]
   ```

   If you explicitly provide a rule for the named argument it will override the default rules stored in `Options[]`

   ```
   fx[{1, 2, 3}, panel -> False]
   ```
3. **Filtering options**

   If you want to provide a decorator function for a built in function and you want to pass options to the function that it calls.

   ```
   myplot3D[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, 
      opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
       Plot3D[f, {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, 
      Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot3D]]]]
   ```

   calling that without options, the default options of `Plot3D` are used

   ```
   myplot3D[Im[ArcSin[(x + I y)^4]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
   ```

   [image]

   This changes the method used by `Plot3D`

   ```
   myplot3D[Im[ArcSin[(x + I y)^4]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]],
       ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red}]
   ```

   [image]

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks @rm -rf that looks much better.

Comment: In my option, the code `Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot3D]]]` should like this `Evaluate[Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot3D]]]`. Could you explain it to me. Thanks.