# Retrieving PlotRange from BarChart

Tags: charts

Consider the following data:

```
data1={73.9377, 54.4122, 53.0826, 24.1936};
data2={76.828, 49.1673, 45.7883, 18.9015};
```

I defined my own `BarChart` as follows:

```
MyBarCharts[list_]:= 
 BarChart[
   list,
   Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}
 ]
```

When applying `MyBarCharts` to `data1` and `data2` I get (not really surprising) two different (with regard to the coordinate system) plots. Now I would like to have for both plots the exact same coordinate system. I know that with `Histogram` it works as follows:

```
Histogram[
data2,
PlotRange -> Part[PlotRange /. Options[Histogram[
                                       data1,
                                       PlotRange -> Automatic
                                       ],PlotRange], 2],
Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}]
```

But the implementation of that approach in `MyBarCharts` does not give the desired result. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You could use my function [graphicsInformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) to obtain the PlotRange of a Graphics object, including those generated by BarChart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting the `PlotRange` from a `BarChart` is not as straightforward as it should be. If no `PlotRange` is specified in creating the chart, then `Options` will return `PlotRange -> All` and `AbsoluteOptions` will return `PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}`

```
bc = BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}];

Options[bc, PlotRange]
(* {PlotRange -> All} *)

AbsoluteOptions[bc, PlotRange]
(* {PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}} *)
```

The incorrect result from `AbsoluteOptions` appears to be related to the presence of dynamic objects in the graphics expression (i.e. the bars with their mouseover effects) . I don't know *why* this causes `AbsoluteOptions` to go wrong, but a workaround is to replace the dynamic bars with straighforward rectangles, allowing `AbsoluteOptions` to extract the correct `PlotRange`. Thus, a replacement for `AbsoluteOptions` for BarCharts is:

```
barChartOptions[chart_, opts___] := 
 AbsoluteOptions[chart /. 
  Tooltip[StatusArea[RawBoxes[DynamicBox[{_, RectangleBox[data__]}]], _], _] :> 
    Rectangle[data], opts]

barChartOptions[bc, PlotRange]
(* {PlotRange -> {{0.545455, 4.45455}, {0., 4.}}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest redefining your `MyBarCharts` to take additional options as:

```
MyBarCharts[list_, options:OptionsPattern[]] := 
    BarChart[list, Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, options]
```

Then you can supply a plot range that's the same for both as:

```
MyBarCharts[data1, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 75}}]
MyBarCharts[data2, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 75}}]
```

Comment: I'd change `options___` to `options:OptionsPattern[]` as it is clearer in intent.

Comment: I want Mathematica to define its own "global" plot range, as I have to plot hundreds of histograms.

Comment: It's relatively easy to work out what the PlotRange will be for bar charts. E.g. `data = {{-2, -3}, {-5, -6}, {-7, -8}, {-9, -10}}; BarChart[data, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Length@Flatten@data + 1}, {Min@{data, 0}, 
    Max@{data, 0}}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to R.M's answer I suggest that you implement a set of custom options for `MyBarCharts`.  You can then use `SetOptions` to define defaults for your function, pass `BarChart` options to your function, etc.  I described in some detail how to do this here:

[Create a Function with Customized Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/358/121)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6159392/618728) for the context of that answer.