# Using the same frame ticks for two different histograms

Tags: plotting

Consider the following:

```
SetOptions[Histogram, BarOrigin -> Left, 
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic];

data1 = {Table[1, {i, 5}], Table[5, {i, 50}], Table[3, {i, 25}], 
   Table[4, {i, 20}]};
data2 = {Table[1, {i, 3}], Table[5, {i, 20}], Table[3, {i, 25}]};
data3 = {Table[1, {i, 3}], Table[5, {i, 20}], Table[4, {i, 15}]};

histo1 = Histogram[data1]
histo2a = Show[Histogram[data1, ChartElements -> None],Histogram[data2]]
histo3a = Show[Histogram[data1, ChartElements -> None],Histogram[data3]]

histo2b = Show[Histogram[data1], Histogram[data2, ChartStyle -> Red]]    
histo3b = Show[Histogram[data1], Histogram[data3, ChartStyle -> Red]]
```

I would like to use the same frame/coordinate system for `histo2a` and `histo3a` as in `histo1`. `histo3b` shows how it should be (only without the grey part) and `histo2a` how it should not be. `histo2b`in addition shows the disadvantage of the `Show[]`-approach (one bar exceeds the frame).

Due to the latter, I was trying to extract the FrameTicks-values from `histo1` and to use them for `Histogram[data2]` and `Histogram[data3] but neither`Options[histo1,FrameTicks]`,`AbsoluteOptions[histo1,FrameTicks]`nor`HistogramList[data1]` return help.

Now I would like to use exactly the same frame ticks, which were calculated based on `data1` for `histo2`.

Neither `Options[histo1,FrameTicks]`, `AbsoluteOptions[histo1,FrameTicks]` or `HistogramList[data1]` help. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: So `Histogram[data2,{HistogramList[data1][[1]]}]` does not do what you want ?

Comment: Do you want also the same bins used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving PlotRange form BarChart](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/retrieving-plotrange-form-barchart)

Comment: No, please see below.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

```
SetOptions[Histogram, BarOrigin -> Left, 
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic];

data1 = Table[BesselJ[1, x], {x, 0, 500}];
data2 = Table[BesselJ[1, x], {x, 0, 100}];
GraphicsGrid[{{
   histo1 = Histogram[data1],
   histo2 = Histogram[data2],
   Show[
    Histogram[data2, ChartElements -> None], 
    Histogram[data1, {HistogramList[data2][[1]]}]]}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

use just

```
Show[Histogram[data2, ChartElements -> None], Histogram[data1]]
```

if you don't want to reuse the same bins:

[image]

Comment: This is almost, what I was looking for, but please take a look at my edit.