# Retrieving PlotRange from BarChart in Mathematica 11

Tags: plotting, options

Further to the accepted answer to this question: [Retrieving PlotRange from BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16792/363), how can this be done in version 11?

In version 7 it worked like this.

[image]

In version 11 it doesn't work.

[image]

*Code for copy & paste*

```
bc = BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
Options[bc, PlotRange]
AbsoluteOptions[bc, PlotRange]
```

Further to J.M.'s comment `` Charting`get2DPlotRange[] `` is not a perfect replacement for `AbsoluteOptions` although it is of some use.

Here is a more complex example for illustration:

```
vals = {37.0186, 40.9317, -56.0248, -21.9255};
{vmin, vmax} = Through[{Min, Max}[vals]];
interval = If[Max[0, vmax] - Min[0, vmin] > 50, 20, 10];
frameticks = {#, #, {0, 0.01}} & /@ ((Range[21] - 11)*interval);
f[l_, p_, r_] := BarChart[vals, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Round[#1],
       If[Round[#1] < 1, l, After]] &), BarOrigin -> Left,
   BarSpacing -> 0.8, PlotRangePadding -> {interval, p},
   Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, Ticks -> None,
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {frameticks, None}},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> {All, r}];
```

in Version 7

```
Print[chart = f[Right, 0.4, {0, 6.4}]];
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[chart, PlotRange]
```

> {{-56.0248, 40.9317}, {0., 6.4}}

in Version 11

```
chart = f[Before, 0, {0.5, 4.5}];
Print[Show[chart,
   Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.3], AbsoluteThickness[0.25],
     Style[Line[{{0, 0.5}, {0, 4.5}}], Antialiasing -> False]}]]];
Charting`get2DPlotRange[chart]
```

> {{-76.0248, 60.9317}, {0.722222, 4.27778}}

However, further to rcollyer's comment

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[chart, False]
```

> {{-56.0248, 40.9317}, {0.722222, 4.27778}}

The x minimum and maximum match version 7.

Comment: I confirm same behaviour on version 11

Comment: ``Charting`get2DPlotRange[]`` still works, tho.

Comment: @J.M. That's useful. I can obtain Ymax by undoing the 5% padding: `ymax = Charting\`get2DPlotRange[bc][[2, 2]]/1.05` yielding 4.

Comment: ``Charting`get2DPlotRange`` accepts a second argument to tell it to add the padding, or not, e.g. ``Charting`get2DPlotRange[bc, False][[2,2]]`` returns 4.

Comment: @rcollyer Aha! That works.  Undocumented of course. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisDegnen note, that it still gives the smaller range in your new example in your post, and to a large extent is as expected since it really just gives you the range you need to show everything.

Answer (score 3):

You could use my function [graphicsInformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) to do this:

```
bc=BarChart[{1,2,3,4},PerformanceGoal->"Speed"];
"PlotRange" /. graphicsInformation[bc]
```

> {{-0.0840242, 5.09461}, {-0.0860215, 4.21505}}

For your other examples:

```
"PlotRange" /. graphicsInformation[f[Right, 0.4, {0, 6.4}]]
"PlotRange" /. graphicsInformation[f[Before,0,{0.5,4.5}]]
```

> {{-76.0248, 60.9317}, {-0.4, 6.8}}
>
> {{-76.0248, 60.9317}, {0.5, 4.5}}