# What's a good style for inheriting Options[] of built-in function?

Tags: functions, options

```
Options[myPlot] = Options[Plot];
myPlot[args___] := ...
```

When defining a "wrapper" function like the above, I'd like it to inherit the `` System` `` function's options.  Should I use `Options[myPlot] = Options[Plot]` or `Options[myPlot] := Options[Plot]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use the first style you gave:

```
Options[tListPlot]=Join[
    Options[ListPlot],
    Options[tLegend],
    {
        Rule[ShowLegend,False]
    }
];
```

The function is then defined as

```
tListPlot[data_,options:OptionsPattern[]]:=...
```

I don't see any reason to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in this context. **EDIT** As Brett Champion mentions in the comments, the default options for

```
System`Plot
```

will change if you use `SetOptions` on `Plot`. Hence, if you want your custom plot to always have the same options as `Plot`, use `:=`. I would prefer to specifically change the options for my Plot separately, so I would still use simply `Set` (`=`).

You might also want to check out this instructive question on Options in custom functions: [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options)

Comment: The default options of `Plot` will change if you use `SetOptions`.  Using `SetDelayed` will pick up that change, unless `SetOptions` has also been applied to `myPlot`.

Comment: +1 Thanks @BrettChampion, I didn't even think of that. I updated the answer to reflect that possibility.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that `FilterRules` can be used to strip out any additional options that are not present in the wrapped function.