# Prevent Export from overwriting files

Tags: functions, export, files-and-directories

`Export["filepath1",Expression1]` works for me, but if `filepath1` already exists, it will be overwritten. I'd like `Export` to notify me and ask for a confirmation, if it tries to overwrite `filepath1`.

I was thinking of creating a child function `Export1` that would:

1. check if the target file exists
2. when 1. obtains, ask if I'd like to overwrite
3. when 2. obtains and I confirm, pass all the parameters and attributes to the parent function `Export`

So, I'd like to create a "child" function that would have exactly the same syntax as the "parent" one, but would be doing an extra check.

What is the best way to do it?

P.S.

`Export` doesn't have attributes (like, say, `Plot` has `PlotRange -> All`), but I'd like to learn how to create a modified child function that would accept and pass not only the parameters, but also attributes to the parent one.

Comment: user, please see my updated answer.  I realized that the normal `OptionsPattern` method recommended in the link is not applicable to `Export`.  Sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your basic requirement is met with:

```
safeExport[file_String, args___] :=
  If[
    ! FileExistsQ[file] || ChoiceDialog["File already exists. Overwrite?"], 
    Export[file, args],
    $Failed
  ]
```

What you describe as "attributes" (e.g. `PlotRange -> All`) are known as [*Options*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OptionsManagement.html) or *named optional arguments*.  (See [Attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html) for a description of what that term means in *Mathematica*.)  To learn how to set up Options please see:

- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121)

My answer to that question specifically deals with a custom function that is an extension of a built-in, with additional Options.

---

Regarding the Options aspect of my answer I realize there is a problem when trying to apply the method described in my linked answer.  This is because `Export` has no "official" Options (`Option[Export]` returns `{}`) despite taking a variety of special options for its different formats.  Therefore if one follows my guide and uses a pattern like `OptionsPattern[{Export, export2}]` in the definition of a function `export2` you will get error messages like:

```
export2["foo.gif", {1, 2, 3}, "DitheringMethod" -> None]
```

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option DitheringMethod for {Export,export2}. >>

Essentially `Export` breaks the new Options convention since it does not have rigorously defined Options.  One could use the deprecated method [`OptionQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionQ.html) described by Leonid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6625219/618728), but I think if Option-like behavior is needed it would be better to use a different workaround.  I propose:

```
Options[export2] = {"Confirmation" -> True};

export2[OptionsPattern[]] := If[OptionValue["Confirmation"], safeExport, Export]
```

Usage examples:

```
export2[]["foo.gif", {1, 2, 3}, "DitheringMethod" -> None]

SetOptions[export2, "Confirmation" -> False];
export2[]["foo.gif", {1, 2, 3}, "DitheringMethod" -> None]

export2["Confirmation" -> True]["foo.gif", {1, 2, 3}, "DitheringMethod" -> None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 11.0, it is possible to do

```
Export[ "file.ext" , foo , OverwriteTarget -> False ]
```

If `file.ext` exists, the export will fail.  There is no built-in option to ask for confirmation though.

Documentation for [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) suggests that there exists an option `OverwriteTarget -> "KeepBoth"` which preserves the existing file and exports to a new one. On my laptop, `Export[ "/tmp/x.pdf", foo, OverwriteTarget -> "KeepBoth" ]` created files `x.pdf`, then `x--2.pdf` etc.