# how to print "output cells" in PDF format on one page each cell

Tags: code-request

I have a notebook with various output cells including some graphs. I like to print only the output cells in PDF format, but each output cell should be fit into a separate page. Sometimes, pictures are large to print on one page, in which case a one-page-fit is desirable.

I used the following `Code` taken from this forum's depository.

```
 cellCounter = 1;
 Map[
 Export[
 StringJoin["cell-", ToString[cellCounter++], ".pdf"],
 NotebookRead[#]] &, 
 Cells[]];
```

This code produces pdf files of all the cells in a notebook, but I cannot locate where they are saved. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: use `Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}]` instead of `Cells[]`?

Comment: @kglr: I run the revised code but still I cannot find the PDF files created. The code indicates the names of the PDF files but I do not know where the PDF files are store?

Comment: does `Directory[]` help?

Comment: @kglr: It works. Now I can see the PDFs but still some PDFs are overflowing the single page. Is there a command to fit one output on a single page at a time?

Comment: Maybe using `ImageSize -> Full` or `ImageSize -> All` in `Export`?

Comment: @kglr: Yes it worked. I used `ImageSize->Scaled[0.8]`, which fits well. Thank you.

Comment: @kglr: I edited my answer with a title Watch out!!!. Do you have any suggestions to address the caveat I pointed out? Thank you very much for your useful comments.

Comment: [Prevent Export from overwriting files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75745/125) and/or [Better random (unique) file name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201552/125) may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer below merely revises the `Code` given in the question with @kglr's comments to achieve the objective stated in the question. I thought this might be useful for others in this forum, who aim to automatically print out `output cells` or `input cells` in either PNG or PDF or any other format of interest. Below, I show the cases for PDF and PNG.

```
SetDirectory["(*directory address for saving the outputs created*)" ]; 
cellCounter = 1;
Map[Export[StringJoin["cell-", 
  ToString[cellCounter++], ".png"], 
  NotebookRead[#], ImageSize -> Scaled[.85]]&, 
  Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}]];
```

The above `code` creates `png` files of output cells in the notebook with `Imagesize->Scaled[.80]`, which adjusts the size of the output files to fit one output into a single page. One may adjust the `ImageSize->Scaled[...]` to print out the output in the desired size.

If one wants to print out the outputs in PDF format, however, replace PNG with PDF in the above code.

The `code` below performs the same task for `input cells` to create PDF files.

```
Map[Export[StringJoin["cell-",
   ToString[cellCounter++], ".pdf"],
   NotebookRead[#],Imagesize->Scaled[0.8]]&,
   Cells[CellStyle\[Rule]{"Input"}]];
```

**Watch out!!!**
The above `Code` should be placed at the very end of the notebook to pick up the already generated outputs and/or inputs. One caveat is that the outputs named as `cell1`, `cell2`, etc no matter which notebook you are using. Therefore, the outputs created from a notebook will be overwritten on the outputs created from another notebook. I will revise my answer as soon as I find a solution to this caveat.

**EDIT**
To prevent overwriting output cells, we use recognizable names. Change `cell-` in the `code` above with `cell-AA-`. This can easily prevent overwriting outputs as the outputs will be saved with such names as `cell-AA-1, cell-AA-2, etc`.

Comment: Tugrul, why not add the name of the notebook along with the style of the cell (in vs out)? That would surely prevent overwriting. You might also try some variant of the day’s date that you are running the code.

Comment: @CA Trevillian: You are absolutely right. I will just replace the cell- with the name of the notebook. This will solve one of the problems I have. another thing is as you said insert time of the day but I do not know how to write that code. Could you please give me a line of example for this so that I can edit my answer? Thank you.

Comment: Tugrul, maybe something like this? `StringReplace[DateString@Today, “ “ -> “-“]` ? These commands should give you good inspiration, at least!

Comment: @CA Trevillian: `DateString[]` works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Tugrul, great to hear! The `StringReplace` may be necessary for some file systems that do not allow white-spacing of file names, in-case you may run into issues using this.