# Create function with pre-specified and optional additional options

Tags: function-construction, options

I am trying to get my head around `Options`, `OptionsPattern`, etc. - I have looked e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) but am still struggling.

Say I want to create a "customised" version of `FullSimplify`, (call it `fs`) which is supposed to

1. always use a certain set of assumptions
2. allow for the input of additional assumptions.

Example: always assume `a<0`, sometimes add `b>0`. So the desired result would be:

```
Column[{
FullSimplify[Sqrt[a^2]],
fs[Sqrt[a^2]],
fs[Sqrt[a^2 b^2],
fs[Sqrt[a^2 b^2],{b>0}]
}]
```

> Sqrt[a]
>   -a
>   -a Sqrt[b]
>   -a b

Now my question is how to define `fs`(and the "default" assumption) properly. My (lousy) current attempt is something like

```
std:={a<0}; (* or "=" instead? *)
Options[fs]=OptionsPattern[Assumptions -> {a < 0}];
(* do I need to parse the other options of FullSimplify as well? *)
fs[x_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=FullSimplify[x,...]
(* how do I add the option {b>0} s.t. it becomes an _additional_ assumption? *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to specify default options for `fs` independently from those of `FullSimplify`, you could do

```
Options[fs] = {Assumptions :> a < 0 && $Assumptions};

fs[expr_, assum_ : {}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    FullSimplify[expr, assum, Join[{opts}, Options[fs]]]

{FullSimplify[Sqrt[a^2]], fs[Sqrt[a^2]], fs[Sqrt[a^2 b^2]], fs[Sqrt[a^2 b^2], {b > 0}]}
(* {Sqrt[a^2], -a, -a Sqrt[b^2], -a b} *)
```

If you do want to be able to define all of the default options of `fs` independently, you can instead set

```
Options[fs] = Options[FullSimplify] /. 
                (Assumptions :> _) -> (Assumptions :> a < 0 && $Assumptions)
(* {Assumptions :> a < 0 && $Assumptions, ComplexityFunction -> Automatic, ExcludedForms -> {}, TimeConstraint -> \[Infinity], TransformationFunctions -> Automatic, Trig -> True} *)
```

with the other function definitions as before. Then you could have something like

```
SetOptions[fs, TimeConstraint -> 1]
(* {Assumptions :> a < 0 && $Assumptions, ComplexityFunction -> Automatic, ExcludedForms -> {}, 
TimeConstraint -> 1, TransformationFunctions -> Automatic, Trig -> True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! Since I don't need to specify further options, your first solution does just fine.

Just to be sure: I don't need to add anything like `SetAttributes[fs,HoldRest]` to ensure the assumption `assum` doesn't get evaluated too early?

Comment: Well, `FullSimplify` doesn't have `HoldRest`, so I don't think adding it to `fs` will make any difference. If you're wondering about the use of `RuleDelayed` in the `Assumptions` option, I think that's to allow the value of the variable `$Assumptions` to be changed after the default option is defined.

Comment: Edited my answer to shorten the function definition using a default argument.