# How to build private function with built-in function's option

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

Since this code work well:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range, 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 8]
```

[image]

I want to set `"IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 8` in every time to use `BenchmarkPlot`.So I want to make a private function to meet this need,and I hope `Options[myBen]` will give all option.

#### First Try

```
Options[myBen1] = {"IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 8};
myBen1[x__, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[x, opt]
myBen1[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range]
```

[image]

#### Second Try

```
SetOptions[myBen2, {"IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 8}];
myBen2 := GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot
myBen2[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range]
```

[image]

As you see,the two option don't work both in this two tries.What's fault on my code?

---

PS:
`` Options[GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot] `` don't include the option of `TimeConstraint`.But it indeed take effect in fact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### New analysis (in v10.1)

For your newly stated goal:

> If I don't want to build a new function.I just wanna change the `` GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot ``'s default option into `{"IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> .8}`. ... Can it be implemented?

The standard options model in *Mathematica* means that this *should* work:

```
Options[BenchmarkPlot] =
  {TimeConstraint -> 8, MaxIterations -> 1024, 
   "IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic};
```

It does not however.  That means that `BenchmarkPlot` or one of its subordinate functions is not written correctly.  Let's have a look.  Using `PrintDefinitions` from the same package we find that our code will call

```
GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`plot
```

Which has the definition (contexts omitted):

```
plot[data_Association, opts___Rule] := 
  ListLogLogPlot[
   Sequence @@ 
    addfits[data,
     Lookup[{opts}, "Models", Automatic], 
     MemberQ[{opts}, "IncludeFits" -> True]],
   FilterOptions[opts], 
   PlotLegends -> fstyle[Keys[data]], GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotMarkers -> {$pmarker}, GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[0.05`], 
   AxesLabel -> {"n", "time (s)"}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {Full, 
     With[{v = Values[data][[All, All, 2]]}, {LogFloor[Min[v]]*1.1`^(-1), 
       LogCeiling[Max[v]]*1.1`}]}];
```

Please draw your attention to the line `MemberQ[{opts}, "IncludeFits" -> True]` and note that here `opts` is the pattern that will match *explicit* options given to this function and nothing else.  `BenchmarkPlot` *does not* pass all options to this function either.  This means that *only* explicit appearences of `"IncludeFits"` will have effect.  (Likewise for `"Models"` from the line above.)

To correct this we either need to expressly pass all of `Options[BenchmarkPlot]` to this inner `plot` function, or we need to modify `plot` so that it considers `Options[BenchmarkPlot]`.  I'll do the latter.

```
<< "GeneralUtilities`"

With[{plot = GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`plot},
  PrependTo[DownValues[plot],
    HoldPattern[plot[arg___]] :> 
      Block[{$fixGUBPopts = True}, 
        plot[arg, Sequence @@ Options[BenchmarkPlot]]
      ] /; ! TrueQ[$fixGUBPopts]
  ]
];

Options[BenchmarkPlot] =
  {TimeConstraint -> 8, MaxIterations -> 1024,
   "IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic};

BenchmarkPlot[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range]
```

[image]

---

#### Old answer

I wrote a fairly lengthy answer hoping to guide just this sort of thing; please take a look:

- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options/358#358)

From your comment

> But `Options[myBen4]` get `{}`. I hope it can get all options. Can it be implement?

I think you want something like this.

```
Options[myBen] = {"IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic, 
   TimeConstraint -> .8};

myBen[args__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 BenchmarkPlot[args, opts, Sequence @@ Options[myBen]]

myBen[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [clouddn.com](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-19-15-16-35.png))</sub>

And it meet the extra need:

```
Options[myBen]
```

> {"IncludeFits"->True,Models->Automatic,TimeConstraint->0.8}

Comment: Not very same to you output.Look [here](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-19-15-00-13.png).

Comment: @yode That does not make sense.  Your output would indicate that the line `Options[myBen] = Options[BenchmarkPlot];` failed to work correctly, and I can only see that happening if you failed to load **GeneralUtilities** first or had an existing definition on `myBen`.  Would you please restart *Mathematica* and try again?

Comment: In version 11, `TimeConstraint` has gone inexplicably missing from `Options[BenchmarkPlot]`.  `TimeConstraint` is still recognized internally by the implementation.  `MaxIterations` is missing as well, but I don't that option was ever actually implemented, even in V10.1.

Comment: I make a edit for fit my case.It's seem I just omit that `Sequence @@ Options[myBen]`.Thanks your answer very very much. :)

Comment: @WReach Thanks for explaining; I was really confused by that!

Comment: If I don't want to build a new function.I just wanna change the ``GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot``'s defult option into `{"IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> .8}`.And the `Options[BenchmarkPlot]` also can give all options still.Can it be implemented?

Comment: @yode You mean just `Options[BenchmarkPlot] = {TimeConstraint -> 8, MaxIterations -> 1024, 
   "IncludeFits" -> True, "Models" -> Automatic};` ?

Comment: It's work for you?I have tried it before.Look [here](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-19-15-51-43.png).

Comment: @yode Ah, so I see, finally!  No, it does not work, but I believe it should.  I am working on a different problem but I shall take a look at this in a few minutes.  I expect to find a bug or at least an unusual design in `BenchmarkPlot`.

Comment: @yode The problem is just as I expected.  I shall write this up soon.

Comment: @yode Complete.  Hopefully my patch still works in version 11.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53893/discussion-between-yode-and-mr-wizard).

Comment: It's seem it don't work in `"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 8, 2016)"`.Look [here](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-19-21-59-24.png)

Comment: @WReach could you perhaps help?  I do not believe I can be of further assistance with the version I am using.

Comment: In V11.0.1, `plot` is in a different internal package.  The patch needs to be applied to ``GeneralUtilities`Performance`PackagePrivate`plot``.  With that change, it works as advertised.

Comment: The original patch works up to V10.3.1.  The updated patch is needed from V10.4 onward.

Answer (score 4):

Including the options in the definition of your auxiliary function seems to work fine:

```
myBen3[x__, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[x, opt, "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

Above I left off the `TimeConstraint` option from the definition on purpose, because I wanted to showcase the fact that the helper function still correctly passes on extra options to `BenchmarkPlot`. Compare for instance:

```
myBen3[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range, TimeConstraint -> 0.3]
myBen3[{SortBy[#, Identity] &, Sort}, Range]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

So a more complete definition would be:

```
myBen4[x__, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[x, opt, "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 8]
```

Comment: But `Options[myBen4]` get `{}`.I hope to get all option.Can it be implement?

Comment: If not,I can do it just by ``myBen := GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[##, "IncludeFits" -> True, 
   TimeConstraint -> 8] &``