# Combine two options lists

Tags: syntax

I have 2 functions `Top` and `Bottom` that each have an options list parameter.

```
Top[quads_, optsTop_: OptionsPattern[]]  
Bottom[quads_, optsBottom_: OptionsPattern[]]
```

Function `Top` eventually calls function `Bottom` and passes the options it received directly to the `Bottom` function.  This works like a charm.
However now I want to add some options to the ones received in `Top` to the call to `Bottom`.  These option lists are not lists so an append doesn't work.  However, I have no idea how to to this.
So conceptually I want to call (from within `Top`)

```
Bottom[quads, Append[opsTop, more->"more"]]
```

Comment: Just use `Bottom[quads, opsTop, more->"more"]` or `Bottom[quads, more->"more", opsTop]`. The latter should prefer `more->"more"` over any specification of `more` in `opsTop` (options are treated first in-last out).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't get it working yet but I guess your answer is correct.  I have had a lot of trouble with the Mathematica syntax, especially since it is unlike any  other programming language.

Comment: Maybe the issue lies somewhere else. Please consider to provide the whole code you use (maybe reduced by the parts that do not involve handling of options). Ping me with an @ in front of my name in a comment. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Willy, if you use `optsTop : OptionsPattern[]` (and `optsBottom : OptionsPattern[]`)  when you define `Top` (resp., `Bottom`), then you can use Henrik's suggestion to call `Top` or `Bottom` with any sequence of options.

Comment: That here seems to explain what you want: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/355/187 If it indeed solves your problem, I would close this question as a duplicate.